# nginix not listening port 80

Tags: nginx, port

Why is `ngnix` not listening port `80` ?

I want `ngnix` to forward all traffic from port 80 to port `localhost:3000`.

I want to stop direct direct access to port 3000 at same time and ensure that only port 80 traffic is allowed.

My application is based on `nuxt.js`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name www.ec2-35-154-54-186.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com;

    location / {
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header   Host $http_host;
        proxy_pass         "http://localhost:3000";
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the error you receive when you try to run `nginx` on port 80? Did you check if there's any other process that's currently using that port? Which operating system are you using? If it's windows, do you have Skype running (skype uses 80)?